# Loop through an ITable LINQ.Data LINQ to SQL

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have the follofing code:

```
...
string curTable = "DTMConsole.DataModels";

var s = wtcDb.GetTable(Type.GetType(curTable));

PropertyInfo[] pList = s.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

   foreach (var p in pList)
   {
      System.Console.Write(p.GetValue(s, null).ToString());
   }
```

...

wtcDb is a DataContext. DataModels is an Entity Table. I'm trying to get the list of all elements (properties) in the s. But it simple doesn't work. I get 2 Properties at all. 1 is the name of the DataContext and the other is a Bool (readOnly). But the class DataModels is much more wider.
How to iterate correctly through the ITable even though the incoming parameters are not strongly typed ?

Comment: I wanna to add. Tryed to iterate also through the s variable but it gives me an Sqlexception. provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing the ITable's property.

```
    var   s =  wtcDb.GetTable(Type.GetType(curTable));
    PropertyInfo[] pList = s.ElementType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

    foreach (var obj in s)
    {
        foreach (var p in pList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p.GetValue(obj, null));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok..and how to reference the DTMConsole.DataModels Entity properties. I need to have this not hard coded .

Comment: I need to read all the Values of the Entity simply by passing the Tablename (the entity name). I'm using the GetTable to retrieve the table but since I don't know at runtime the class name, i load the class name through curTable and assume that the result is simply an object with some properties and method..This is what I want to achieve

Comment: I assumed that the GetTable method of the datacontext creates already an instance of the DataModels entity which I require and fills it with the data.

Comment: @ClaudioFerraro - That's true. I did't understood what you want. see my edited post.

Comment: I don't know why with your code I continue to get. Sqlexception. provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26... on foreach( var obj in s)

Comment: @ClaudioFerraro - Double check the connection string. Take a look at  - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/05/13/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-server-instance-specified.aspx